# Dropdown list didnt bind after retrieval from REST Api

Tags: angular, typescript, rest

I have a REST API that returns the following results:

```
{
      listOfItemList: [
      { 
           "itemId": "2",
           "itemName": "Apple"
       }
}
```

In the form, I have created a sample JSON for testing:

```
itemList: = [
            {itemId: '1', name: 'Watermelon'},
            {itemId: '2', name: 'Apple'}
         ]
```

API call on ngOnInit()

```
items : IItem[];

public getItemList() : void {
      this.itemService.getItemList().subscribe(
        (res: any) => {
               this.items = res.listOfItemList;
        )
        ..
 }
```

UI

```
<p-dropdown [options] = "itemList" optionLabel="itemName" [(ngModel)]="items"></p-dropdown>
```

With the above codes, it doesnt set the selected value as Apple and default as Watermelon.

If I create a  test json object as shown below, it works.

```
selectedItem = {itemId: '2', itemName: 'Apple'}
<p-dropdown [options] = "items" optionalLabel="itemName" [(ngModel)]="selectedItem "></p-dropdown>
```

Whats wrong with the above implementation?

Comment: check your sintax, you has `[options]="items" and `[(ngModel)]="items"`. You need use two differents variables. futhermore if you get from your service an array with an unique element, sure you don't want in subscribe use `this.selectedItem=res.listOfItemList[0]`? (selectedItem equal the value of the first element of the response)

Comment: Hi thanks for highlighting.. it should be [options]="itemList" and [(ngModel)]="items"

Comment: Thanks Eliseo. It works by getting the first element of the array.